# Understanding Mathematical Symbols in Algorithms

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, dynamic-programming

Just a quick question here. I am working on an assignment for algorithms involving dynamic programming.  Don't worry, this isn't a question about my assignment, just a question about understanding a portion of the original question. I am having difficulty understanding what this means:

$T(i, j) = 0 \,\forall\,i, \,j, \,j<i$

So far I understand: $T(i,j)$ is equal to 0 for all $i$.  However, I am not certain how the $j$ and the $j < i$ come into play.  Perhaps I just need some properly placed parentheses?

Any help would be great!

Comment: I think it means T(i,j)=0 when j<i. I read it as "for all i and j, when j<i".

Answer (score 1):

Formally (and IMHO always, if you want to avoid confusion), quantifiers should be placed at the beginning of the formula they govern, and should have only one quantified varibale each.  Thus:
$$\forall i\ \forall j\ \bigl(\ (\,j<i\,)\to (\,T(i,j)=0\,)\ \bigr)\ .$$
Better still, use words instead of symbols:
$$\hbox{for all $i$ and for all $j$, if $j<i$ then $T(i,j)=0$.}$$

Comment: Okay, so $T$ represents a matrix.  I'm guessing the above statement is initializing 
\[
T(i,j)=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
    1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1\\
    \end{array} } \right]
\]
**Note:** I have no idea why the $LaTeX$ isn't being fully processed

Comment: Not quite, it would be initialising$$\pmatrix{?&?&?&\cdots\cr 0&?&?&\cdots\cr 0&0&?&\cdots\cr &\vdots&&\ddots\cr}\ .$$

Comment: BTW: LaTeX not working? - I think you might have put the equation inside [...] instead of \ \[...\ \]